# Qt platform plugin not loading even though it is found

Tags: python, qt, plugins, pyqt5

I have a problem while I load my python pyqt5 gui on a windows vista computer using windows powershell.

I get the following error:-

**qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin coul
x this problem.**

**Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen, webgl, windows.**

It worked perfectly on a windows 10 computer. There had been errors where it was not been able to find the plugin. I have solved that. But now, even though it is able to find the plugin, it doesn't load.

Can you help me out?

Comment: The problem are missing libraries. On linux i will suggest to use ldd on `windows` library file, but I do not know what you should use on Windows.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? I'm a beginner in using PyQt5.

Comment: On Windows you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on `qwindows.dll` and see if there is no dependent libraries missing, try this in your target machine, in your case, run it on Windows Vista. I suspect that the Windows Vista isn't supported by your Qt version!

Comment: I did find a few errors. QT5CORE.DLL, QT5GUI.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL were the files that couldn't be found by the system. I also don't have Qt installed separately in my system. Is that the reason why these files weren't found?

Comment: @madavan: Please see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Get each needed file to package a Qt application (C++, Python, etc), can be a painful task in any operating system. To help us on this, Qt offers for C++ developers on Windows `windeployqt`, a simple tool that analyze your executable and copy all needed files to a deployment folder.

The above paragraph is useful, however, for C++ developers.
Since you're developing your app in Python, other solution may be more adequate.

I had a great experience with [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and i will tell you how to use it:

1. Download and install [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
2. On Windows command prompt type `pip install pyinstaller`.
3. Then on Windows command prompt change the current directory to your `main.py` file location using `cd` command.
4. Now if your Python application has a graphical interface and isn't a console application, create a copy of your `main.py` and rename that copied file to `main.pyw`. This prevent a console window opening in your final application. Remember that `main.py` may have a different name, and you must rename only the file you will pass to [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).
5. Finally type `pyinstaller main.pyw` and wait for completion.
6. If all goes right, you have now a sub folder called `dist` with all needed files to run your python application on a Window machine that have neither Python nor Qt installed.

I was able to run a simple PySide2 application on a Windows 7 machine with neither Python nor Qt installed.

Manual of [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/):

- https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using the conda base environment. I tried many attempts from different discussions about this, but in the end it worked with creating a (new) conda-env and installing dependencies such as matplotlib (which again depends on pyqt which is then also installed by conda)